# Induction proof that $1^3+2^3+...+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4$

Tags: summation, induction

Prove that:

$1^3+2^3+...+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ for $n \in N$

So I am thinking that I need to do a proof by mathematical induction. Here's my attempt:

Let S(n) be the statement $1^3+2^3+...+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ for $n \in N$. When n=1,

$$1^3=\frac{1^2(1+1)^2}{4}$$

$$1=\frac{(2)^2}{4}$$

$$1=\frac{4}{4}$$

So P(1) is true.

Suppose that k is any integer with $k \ge 1$ such that  $p(k)1^3+2^3+...+k^3=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}$ for $k \in N$. Then adding $(k+1)^3$ to both sides,

$$1^3+2^3+...+k^3=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}$$

$$1^3+2^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)^3$$

$$1^3+2^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3}{4}$$

$$1^3+2^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3=\frac{(k+1)^2(k^2+4(k+1)}{4}$$

$$1^3+2^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3=\frac{(k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4)}{4}$$

$$1^3+2^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3=\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}$$

$$1^3+2^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3=\frac{(k+1)^2(k+1+1)^2}{4}=P(k+1)$$

Thus, since we have proved that P(k+1) is true, we can conclude that P(k) is true for all $k \in N$.

How does it look, any edits I should make?

Comment: Looks fine. ${}{}{}$.

Comment: One small error the equal sign in $=P(k+1)$. $P(k+1)$ is not a number, but the expression of the equality of the sum and the formula. I would replace it by "which is exactly the proposition $P(k+1)$"

Comment: Very minor comments: (i) for dots between the plus signs, use \cdots (for low dots use \dots); (ii) I would prefer, for no good reason, to have in the conclusion $P(n)$ is true $\dots$; there are inconsistencies of notation, first it was $S(n)$ then sometimes $P$, and once $p$. In the line after "So $P(1)$ i true there is a strange $p(k)$, and after that "for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is unnecessary, you have already said $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: This may be one of the most duplicated questions on this site.

Comment: @induktio I suppose it may be a duplicate, but I thought my answer was right but I just wanted to fix the very minor flaws (that everyone has been pointing out!) and just looking at that question wouldn't have really done that

Comment: @MathMajor You weren't supposed to look at the *question* but all of the answers given.

Comment: @induktio Of course I meant looking at the quesiton + answers, but for example the not putting an equal sign with the P(k+1) was never addressed in that question. So yes, it may be duplicated. But it was still beneficial and helpful to me to ask this question separately.

Comment: @MathMajor In that case, a comment would be a lot more appropriate than an entirely new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only issue to me is that you should not be saying $\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4} = P(k+1)$. $P$ is a predicate, not a polynomial. In other words, it is a mathematical statement which is either true or false, but it does not possess a numerical value, unlike the arithmetic expression given on the left side. Thus you might instead write $1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + (k+1)^3 = \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4} \implies P(k+1)$.

Having logical connectives (e.g., $\implies$)between each of your equations is probably a good idea as well, because even though your reader likely recognizes that these statements are meant to be taken together, in theory they could just be unrelated statements.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It is good.

I would do it as this. In the first step for $(k+1)$,

Left side:
$$P_{k+1} - P_k = (k+1)^3$$

Right side:
$$P_{k+1}-P_k={{(k+1)^2}{(k+2)^2} \over 4}-{{(k)^2}{(k+1)^2} \over 4}$$
$$P_{k+1}-P_k={1 \over 4}{(k+1)^2}({(k+2)^2-(k)^2})$$
$$P_{k+1}-P_k={1 \over 4}{(k+1)^2}({4k+4})$$
$$P_{k+1}-P_k={(k+1)^3}$$
Therefor:
$L=R$